# Share/Stream live video on LAN network - raspberry

Tags: networking, video, streaming, broadcast

As in the question, I need to share a video in lan by broadcasting.

From server, I've tried with:

```
avconv -i video.mov -c:v libx264 -f mpegts udp://[destinationIP]:1234
```

From client I can play video with:

```
omxplayer udp://serverIP:1234
```

But this works only for one "connection".

What I need is to put the video stream in broadcast that all the clients can read.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you multiple client machines ? you are sending to only one destinationIP. You probally want to use MULTICAST, (or for a quick try BROADCAST) address at destination and client.

Comment: I find the solution by my self, I've already answered to this question.. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution searching on web, especially reading [this page](http://gelliphanindraviswanadhaprasad.org/videolan-streaming-howto/).

For transmit video:

```
avconv -i video.mov -c:v libx264 -f mpegts udp://224.0.0.100:1234
```

From any client in the lan:

```
omxplayer udp://224.0.0.100:1234
```

The trick is to trasmit to the multicast group with the ip range:

. from 224.0.0.0
. to   239.255.255.255

'1234' is the port used to stream.